# Alignment problem with Noto Sans Bengali

Tags: linux, harftex

If I use `Kalpurush` instead of `Noto Sans Bengali`, I've no problem in alignment with this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{harfload, fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11.7in, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Kalpurush}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
%\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
\newfontfamily\en{Noto Sans}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
      দ্রতেরত এরতেরত হগজঘজ ইয়ুত্রুরত্য এরতেরতের দসগদফগদফগ দফগদফগদফগস্ফসদফ সদফসদসদফসদফ সদফ সদফসদফসদফসদফ সদফসদফসস এরতেরতেরত এরতেরতেরত এরতেরতেরতের এরতেরতে রতেরত রতেরত এরতেরত রত্রত রত্রত রত্রত্রত্র রত্রত্র রত্র \\

     {\en Test sdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sds}
\end{document}
```

here's how it is with `Noto Sans Bengali`:

[image]

and with `Kalpurush`:

[image]

How to fix the `Noto Sans Bengali` alignment issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX can't find good places to break the lines in your first paragraph, so it gives up and you get an overfull \hbox. Kalpurush is a narrower font than Noto Sans Bengali and it works OK.

There's two things you can try:

1. Reword the paragraph so you don't get an overfull line.
2. Make the paragraph sloppy so TeX lets you have wider spaces between words, but then you will get underfull lines. In other words you can't win.

   A `sloppypar` environment sets the following parameters: `\tolerance 9999\emergencystretch 3em\hfuzz .5pt \vfuzz \hfuzz`. You can also experiment and adjust these individually.

   `\fussy` returns things to their default. `\fussy` is defined as: `\emergencystretch 0pt \tolerance 200\hfuzz .1pt \vfuzz \hfuzz`.

**Aside:** You should remove the `\\` from the end of your Bengali line. You should never end a paragraph with a manual line break.

## MWE

With `xelatex` since I don't have Harfbuzz set up for `luatex` yet.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11.7in, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Bengali}
\newfontfamily\en{Noto Sans}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
  দ্রতেরত এরতেরত হগজঘজ ইয়ুত্রুরত্য এরতেরতের দসগদফগদফগ দফগদফগদফগস্ফসদফ সদফসদসদফসদফ সদফ সদফসদফসদফসদফ সদফসদফসস এরতেরতেরত এরতেরতেরত এরতেরতেরতের এরতেরতে রতেরত রতেরত এরতেরত রত্রত রত্রত রত্রত্রত্র রত্রত্র রত্র
\end{sloppypar}

{\en Test sdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sds}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: If I don't use \\ or \newline, I don't get any space between paragraphs!

Comment: That is not how to fix that. Remove `\parindent 0pt` and add `\usepackage{parskip}`.

Comment: @EmonHaque, the space between paragraphs is configurable. See the `parskip` package documentation for details.

Comment: I've to add `\parskip=12pt` in preamble instead of \\